# Cut start and end of video file if audio is silent or contains noise

Tags: ffmpeg

I've tried using the following ffmpeg command :

```
ffmpeg -i path/to/input.ts -af silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_silence=0.1:start_threshold=-50dB,areverse,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_silence=0.1:start_threshold=-50dB,areverse path/to/output.ts
```

The command worked and generated a file except it only cut the audio stream and not both the audio stream and video stream.

Is there a way to make it cut both with `ffmpeg` or it's javascript equivalent `fluent-ffmpeg` ?

Comment: Have you seen more or less the same question at superuser? https://superuser.com/q/990357/141595

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Nope i hadn't seen it. Thank you for pointing it out. Sadly, all those solutions won't work for me. I need an ffmpeg command line that can be converted to fluent-ffmpeg.

Comment: Thanks, can you please [edit] your question to include that kind of requirements?